# How to add tab in profile app in IBM Connection-5?

Tags: widget, single-sign-on, ibm-connections

I am currently working on IBM connection5 and having lot of problem and I would appreciate if someone can help me out.

I am trying to integrate one of website into IBM connection5, but the problem is I need to create a Tab in Profile App and add Login fields such as a user name and password field in newly created Tab.

After authentication from the other website, the user get enter into their website and browse whatever he wants to. I need to do it by *single sign-on* (SSO). 
The main problem is I don´t know how to add Tab in Profile App and how to integrate my application (user name and password) to newly created Tab in IBM Conenction5.

Comment: review this tutorial - http://www.slideshare.net/pgodby/ic5-l09-iwidgetprofiles

Answer (score 0):

To add a tab to Profiles please follow the [IBM Connections Documentation - Adding custom widgets to Profiles](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_5.0.0/admin/admin/c_admin_profiles_add_custom_widgets.dita?lang=en).

Comment: the tutorial i posted above does a detailed step by step explanation

Comment: Thanks Guys. I may have other questions. I have developed an application in Java and i need to integrate this app as a widget to IBM Connection. I lack one thing, i need to get the current IBM Connection 5 User Id. Is there Any way, my app can talk to IBM Connection5? and get the Current User ID of IBM Connection5. I used HTTP Session  but i supposed it is to get the user info of my app rather than IBM Connection5